# cant connect to sql server express on server from client

Tags: sql-server, sql

I just install sql server express on server with ip 10.222.117.17. I've been deactivated the firewall so i can ping server from client or my pc.

but when i try to connect with navicat or management studio on my pc. it cant.

Login Timeout expired.
a network-related has occured while establishing a network connection to sql server. sql server is not found or accessible.

please help me what is wrong, and how can i connect to sql server from client.

thanks

Comment: Have you [enabled network connections in SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165718(v=sql.105).aspx)?

Answer (score -1):

This will help you to solve you SQL Connection Issues.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/docast/2014/10/24/tips-and-tricks-to-fix-sql-connectivity-issues/